# Bash: iterate over several files and perform a different change for each file

Tags: bash, shell, replace, sed, text-processing

I want to change in several txt-files a variable. But this variable shouldn't be equal in every txt-file.
I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
for file in ./*.txt ;do
    for value in $(seq 1 5); do
        sed -i 's/x_max=.*/x_max='$value'/ ' $file
    done
done
```

So every x_max has got the value:5

Comment: Of course. You run each of the five replacements on each file. So they all end up with the last edit.

Comment: You are creating a loop before `sed` runs incrementing at every iteration. since the file is being over-written, every file will have `x_max=5`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Replace each file only once, with a different value each time.

```
value=1
for file in *.txt; do
  sed -i 's/x_max=.*/x_max='$value'/' $file
  value=$((value + 1))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do it - only iterate once and raise the counter by 1 after each run:

```
counter=1

for file in ./*.txt ;do
    sed -i 's/x_max=.*/x_max='$counter'/ ' $file
    (( counter++ ))
done
```